# Send log data from ec2 logs to eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I want to send logs data from my EC2 instance (Ubuntu) to an AWS eventbridge where I can then send them to multiple endpoints. e.g. if someone performs a root user operation on the server this is written to/var/log/auth.log, I would then like this change in the log to be sent to eventbridge where it can then be routed to other locations, how can achieve this?

cheers

N.B.
I have tried using the cloudwatch agent but I can't figure how to get the logs to eventbridge once they're in a log group, so if there is a way I can this that would also work.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure how to get the logs to eventbridge once they're in a log group, so if there is a way I can this that would also work.

Once your CloudWatch Agent writes relevant logs to CloudWatch logs, you can setup a [subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) on your log group.

The filter would stream logs of interest (e.g. those that contain ssh) into a **lambda function**. How to set it up is shown in:

- [Example 2: Subscription Filters with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample)

The lambda, using events api, e.g. in boto3, could process the log stream, filter out messages, construct events and publish them to the event bridge.